# TRÅDFRI lights and multiple swiches

Tags: ikea-tradfri

I have 3 TRÅDFRI 30W drivers in my kitchen, and succeeded in pairing all of them to the same remote. However, if I pair a lamp to a 2nd remote, it stops responding to the first one. I was hoping to use 2 remotes, to get 2-way control.

From the documentation, one remote can control 10 lamp drivers, but it isn't clear to me if only one remote can drive a lamp at once. If it's possible, is there a reliable way to set it up?

I don't have a gateway. If I have a gateway, can I use IFTTT to cross connect two driver/remote pairs or subsets to keep the drivers in sync in the way that I could do with SonOff?

Comment: you answered your own question .... `However, if I pair a lamp to a 2nd remote, it stops responding to the first one.`

Comment: @jsotola, I'm asking if I'm doing something silly, or if the designer has done something monumentally stupid. It's not clear, but I guess from your comment you believe it to be the latter. If you know the designer, maybe you can flag the documentation for an update. Maybe a firmware update would give a different result.

Comment: I need to source this info "managed to get two Tradfri motion sensors paired with one group of lights (it's unsupported, but discussed openly by Ikea on Reddit) - I do have the gateway but thats not involved: you pair one remote steering device with another."

Comment: @jsotola Wrong. Simply undocumented and not obvious.

Comment: none of this worked for me to clone the two remotes. i am using a gateway, not pairing directly to the cabinet lights. after hours of trying, I give up and now this fancy remote is another useless pile of plastic. ive tried at least three different methods including all of those listed here. if anyone has alternative advice, Id be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is from observation, not documented fact)

I don't believe this is possible, even with a gateway.

In the gateway setup, groups are defined by the remote/dimmer/pir. You pair the controller with the gateway then use it to add lights, there is no way to add a second controller to a group.

Also when I did the [work](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2017/04/06/fist-pass-tradfri-mqtt-bridge/) to reverse engineer CoAP protocol I never found a way to get the remote inputs, only notifications about the changes in state of the lights.

I do need to go back and have another low level play with gateway, but it does seem to be a limitation.

Comment: See below: This seems just plain wrong.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is an easy, but undocumented way to do this.

1. Factory reset the remotes (press pair 4x within 5 sec).
2. Pair one remote to a bulb (this may not be necessary, but I did this)
3. Hold the remotes next to each other, press both pair buttons for 10 sec. LEDs on the front come on, then flicker off.
4. Observe both remotes control the 1st bulb.
5. Pair one remote to a 2nd bulb.
6. Observe both remotes control both bulbs.

From [Ikea on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tradfri/comments/7svzk1/comment/dt8jnz5/?st=JF1G7SUK&sh=c8165560)

> You can actually clone two of the same input device if you like. It's
>   not documented but if you keep two input devices close to eachother
>   and hold the pairing button on first one, keep holding it and at the
>   same time hold the pairing button on the other one they will both end
>   up in the same group. (You should get feedback from the LEDs) I'd
>   recommend doing a factory reset on the input device you are trying to
>   add into the group before starting the process.

Comment: oooh, will have to have a play with that. Need to get back to Ikea to get one of the sockets with a switch (have one without which is not that useful...)

Comment: At least their returns policy is great for prototyping a system.

Comment: I have tried the extra remote method, was easy and simple to set up. You can set it up without the app but you won't get the firmware updates. [Multiple Remotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FduBZ.jpg)

Comment: This works perfectly. I even have my Hue bulbs attached to Hue Bridge. The only Ikea hardware here are two switches. Amazing.

Comment: I tried pairing 2 remotes I have, an E1524 and an E1810, but it did not work, unfortunately. The lights (which are ~0.5cm above the power icon on the front) never came on when holding the 2 remotes nearby and holding the pair buttons. I wonder if it's because I used a gateway previously, or because the remotes are different, or because I did not reset the switches...

Answer (score 0):

Really simple. Just hold down both Remote pair button at the exact same time next to each bulb you want to pair with for 10s. Boom!